# C++: get int from any place of vector<byte>

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have big enough

```
std::vector<byte> source
```

and I need to get four bytes from any offset in vector (for example, 10-13 bytes) and convert it to integer.

```
int ByteVector2Int(std::vector &source, int offset)
{
return (source[offset] | source[offset + 1] << 8 | source[offset + 2] << 16 | source[offset + 3] << 24);
}
```

This method called too offen, how I can do that with maximum perfomance?

Comment: What do you have at the moment and why do you believe it is not optimal? Also, did you profile to see whether it actually is a bottleneck?

Comment: Vectors are stored continuously in memory, so if vector and CPU share the same endianness you could probably cast directly to an int. I wouldn't though, unless I really needed to get top performance at all costs. shifts and or would be much more reliable and still pretty fast.

Comment: I changed the text of the post and inserted the current implementation there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `memcpy`. You might be tempted to use `reinterpret_cast`, but then you can easily end up with undefined behavior (for instance due to alignment issues). Also, pass a vector by a *const* reference:

```
int f(const std::vector<std::byte>& v, size_t n)
{
    int temp;
    memcpy(&temp, v.data() + n, sizeof(int));
    return temp;  
}
```

Note that compilers are very good in optimizations. In my case, GCC with `-O2` resulted in:

```
mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
mov     eax, dword ptr [rax + rsi]
ret
```

So, there is no `memcpy` invoked and the assembly is minimal. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/oWGqej

---

**UPDATE (based on question update)**

After edit, you may also notice that the generated assembly is the very same (in my case) as for your approach:

```
int f2(const std::vector<std::byte>& v, size_t n)
{
  return (int)(
     (unsigned int)v[n]
     + ((unsigned int)v[n + 1] << 8)
     + ((unsigned int)v[n + 2] << 16)
     + ((unsigned int)v[n + 3] << 24) );
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/c9dE9W

Note that your code is **not** correct. First, bitwise operations are performed with `std::byte` which overflows, and second, there is no implicit conversion of `std::byte` to `int`.

Comment: @Evg The OP's solution was originally not in the question.

Comment: `Note that your code is not correct. First, bitwise operations are performed with std::byte which overflows` This is not true. There are no arithmetic operations for integers smaller than `int` in C++. They would be promoted so your casts do nothing. Both your and OP's version have a bug however: The arithmetic may overflow the signed int which is UB. A correct solution does the calculation as unsigned, and converts to signed afterwards. Also note that `memcpy` will behave differently depending on native endianness of the CPU while the bit shift version always reads the data as little endian.

Comment: @eerorika I don't fully agree. In OP's code, the result of the shift is stored back in `std::byte`. I cast the source `std::byte` into `int`, therefore, the result is of type `int`. Anyway, agree about `unsigned`.

Comment: There is no storing back into byte in OP's code (whether they use `std::byte` or otherwise). It's a big arithmetic expression whose all operands are either `int` or `byte` which is promoted to `int` (assuming it is an integer type) and result is `int` which is returned from function with return type of `int`.

Comment: @eerorika Check the error message: https://godbolt.org/z/33bK6Y. Also relevant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte. Note by `operator<<`: _Equivalent to:_ `return std::byte(static_cast<unsigned int>(b) << shift);`. `std::byte` is not an arithmetic type. But I agree that we don't know what `byte` means in the question.

Comment: Yes OP's code won't work if they use `std::byte`. It only compiles with `byte` that is an arithmetic type.